# Raspberrypi gpio pin 13 change back to default after setup with RPi.GPIO

Tags: gpio

I use gpio with RPi.GPIO library.I want to change pin 13 (GPIO.23) to OUTPUT mode.
Here is my code:

```
#gpio-test.py
import RPi.GPIO as io
io.setmode(io.BCM)
io.setup(13, io.OUT)
```

Before running this script, I use "gpio readall" to check the gpio,it show like this [befor run script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwHC4.png)

after run this script shows like :
[after run script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XreTZ.png)
But after few secondes, the pin 13 change back to INPUT mode automatic.Change other pins is ok,only this pin 13 cannot.Does anybody know why?

Comment: What you have connected to your pin 18???

Comment: ....Now I found the problem, my workmate changed the config.txt for the temperature sensor.He added this code:`dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup,gpiopin=13`

Comment: thats why i asked you that what you are connecting to pin 13. anyway you got solution.

Answer (score 0):

my workmate changed the config.txt for the temperature sensor.He added this code:dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup,gpiopin=13